# Why does writing datetime from postgres to mysql work?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, python-2.7

This code works, but why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4


import psycopg2
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import *
from sshtunnel import *
import MySQLdb

remote_host='ahost'
port=50000
remote_ssh_port=5434
remote_bind_port=5432
username='ausername'

with SSHTunnelForwarder((remote_host, remote_ssh_port),ssh_username=username, ssh_pkey='/home/conoadmin/.ssh/id_dsa', remote_bind_address = ('localhost', remote_bind_port), local_bind_address = ('localhost', port)):
        pg_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='adb' user='auser' host='localhost' port=50000 password='apasswd'")
        pg_cur = pg_conn.cursor()
        pg_cur.execute('select start from \"Data\" LIMIT 1;')
        liste = pg_cur.fetchall()
        pg_cur.close()

print(liste)


mysql_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                    user='user',
                    passwd='password',
                    db='test')

mysql_cur = mysql_conn.cursor()

for item in liste:
    mysql_cur.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO postdatum(zeit)' 'VALUES(%s)', item)

mysql_conn.commit()
mysql_cur.close()
```

The output of the print command looks like this:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 23, 20, 48, 3),)]
```

The column `zeit` is formated as DATETIME in mysql. Given how one usually inputs data into DATETIME columns ins mysql I expected I would have to rewrite the output from the postgres database, but it appears to work. I don't understand why. And will this be a stable behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psycopg2` and `MySQLdb` convert the database native datetime formats to and from Python datetime.

when you print you see the python internal datetime format, but when you read and write the databases it is converted.